# ¿Existe setTime en php o algo parecido?

Tags: javascript, php, date

En javascript existe algo llamado setTime que hace que algo pase después de un tiempo. Necesito algo parecido pero para php, me ayudan?

para algo como esto, esto no hace lo que quiero.

```
<script>alert('Error: correo ya existente, favor de utilizar utilizar otro.');
setTimeout(() => {
<?php
 header('Location: '. RUTA . '/crearCuenta.php');
 }, 5000);
</script>
 ?>
```

Comment: Ten en cuanta que PHP no terminará de enviar los datos hasta después del timer, no tiene mucho sentido que sea el servidor quien espere. Creo que la solución que has puesto como ejemplo es más correcta, que espere el cliente.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la propia cabecera para que el navegador espere x tiempo antes de redireccionar ejemplo:

```php
<?php

$tiempoEsperaEnSegundos = 10;
$url = 'midominio.com/path';

header("refresh: $tiempoEsperaEnSegundos; url=$url");

echo 'Muestra esto y redirecciona después';
```

Answer (score 0):

sere sincero, casi nunca uso php, pero esto deberia de ayudarte

creo que si quieres que tu script espere algo de tiempo antes de continuar, deberias usar la funcion sleep(x)

```
echo "Hi";
sleep(5);
echo "Finish";
```

te explicare paso a paso, donde esta  el `echo "Hi"`, es el bloque 1 que se ejecuta al instante, cuando el bloque 1 termina, pasamos al `sleep(5);` en esa linea espera 5 segundos y cuando termine, pasa al bloque 2, `echo "Finish"`

Este seria tu codigo para una pagina web por ejemplo

```
<?php
      echo "Hi";
      sleep(5);
      echo "Finish";
?>
```

de hecho, si haces desarrollo web con php, hay algunos hosters que deshabilitan sleep por motivos de seguridad, asi que si no funciona en el hosting que usas, es posible que tengas que alquilar un VPS o comprar un servidor para colocarlo donde vivas